# How to run local node server on subfolder?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, localhost, subdirectory

For an vuejs application.

I need to emulate, in local, a production environment in witch deploy is on a subfolder, like www.domain.com/subfolder1.

How can I configure my local node server so I the local application run on localhost:port/subfolder1?

Comment: here you go
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks, you give me the view for trying in express.

Answer (score 1):

With an already build on /dist folder. This let me try at localhost:8080/custom-sub-path

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use('/custom-sub-path/static', express.static('dist/static'));
app.use('/custom-sub-path', express.static('dist'));

app.get('/custom-sub-path/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});

console.log('serving port 8080');

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

If I understand your question right, I believe you would like to setup a Node.js process running a server (example `localhost:1337`) and you would like to access it @ `http://localhost/subfolder`.

For that you will need to setup a reverse proxy, such as **NGINX**
and create a configuration for forwarding connections to the proccess :

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   location /subfolder {
        # Forward Real IP
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

NGINX will receive the requests at port 80 and when requested with /subfolder it will forward requests to your Node.js Server running at port 1337.

Hope this helped. Good Luck.

Comment: It works but, now the static files are 404 not found ..!!